# BIDS MDX Query opening in Design Mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, bids

I have an rdl file uses custom MDX to generate a dataset.

The file is opening in Design MOde and removing the custom mdx.

How do I stop it from opening in Design Mode?

Many THanks,
S

Answer (score 0):

Strange, it should 'remember' it is custom MDX and open it in custom MDX mode, so you see the written query as opposed to the drag&drop query designer.

I have had something like this happen before, it turned out to be down to a problem with either source control, or some small (Manual) change to the RDL's code - We ended up reverting to an earlier version and all was well.

Any of these apply? Have you tried creating a new report, giving it custom MDX, then reopening it? Do it as a new project, without source control, and it should be fine.

Comment: This should not happen. Create a new dataset with a different name, copy the mdx in and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the custom MDX? If your manually updating the xml then I've found there are two places where the MDX needs to be placed.

The first is in the Query/CommandText element and the second is the Query/rd:DesignerState/QueryDefinition/Query/Statement

These two need to be the same.